# Is this really a hat?

Tags: bug, winter-bash

See the costume [this avatar](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/117002/balarka-sen) is wearing. Is this really a hat? It says the user has no hats. Bug bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it is the Hello World hat, which [some google research](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212898/am-i-eligible-for-hats-if-i-join-a-stack-ange-site-after-the-start-of-winter#comment685265_212898) seems to mean the user scored a +1 on their first question. It indeed seems to be a bug.

Comment: "You can accept an answer in 7 minutes." Will do, boss!

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Even if a user's profile does not show the Winter Bash snowflake, you can see their hats by appending `#winter-bash` to the URL for their profile.

Comment: Oh, great! :) $\mathrm{}\\$